# Nuxt 3 #imports should be transformed with real imports

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt 3 and I want to import vuetify.

I've successfully imported vuetify and I can use the componetns of vuetify. And everythinh is working fine, but I am getting a warning and don't know how to fix it

I've added vuetify as a plugin.

This is the warning:

> [nuxt] #imports should be transformed with real imports. There seems to be something wrong with the imports plugin.

This is my `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: [
            'vuetify'
        ]
    }
})
```

And my `plugins/vuetify.ts`

```js
import {defineNuxtPlugin} from "#app";
import {createVuetify} from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        components,
        directives
    })

    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[From here](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#ssr), it looks like you also need to set the following

```js
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  ssr: true,
})
```